# Importing jboss ResteasyClient in Spring Boot prevents it from booting

Tags: java, spring-boot, pom.xml, resteasy, keycloak

We are setting up a Spring Boot (v2.0.5) server application backed up by a Keycloak auth server.

Keycloak provides some Java Admin API (keycloak-admin-client) which unfortunately require as a dependency the ResteasyClient found in the org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-client package.

However if I add this dependency to the POM as

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>resteasy-client</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

I end up having the following error when the server starts:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jsonb' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jsonb/JsonbAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.json.bind.Jsonb]: Factory method 'jsonb' threw exception; nested exception is javax.json.bind.JsonbException: JSON Binding provider org.eclipse.yasson.JsonBindingProvider not found

I really don't know how to solve this error. Any ideas?

EDIT: Adding the Keycloak related dependencies I've added in POM:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
    <artifactId>keycloak-admin-client</artifactId>
    <version>4.4.0.Final</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>resteasy-client</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak.bom</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-adapter-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${keycloak.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Comment: Can you share all dependencies of keycloak related parts of your POM. I think you need to add dependency to yasson too in your POM.

Comment: @raidensan I added the dependencies in the original question.  Adding the yasson dependency did not work unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think I finally found the solution.

I needed more dependencies in my POM, the full list is:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-client</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.json</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse</groupId>
        <artifactId>yasson</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jackson2-provider</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```